# Why does my Mac Pro think it has another display connected?

Tags: display, graphics, mac-pro, gpu

I just bought an Apple NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT for my 1st gen Mac Pro. It now has a weird issue where it thinks there's another display connected, but there isn't.

System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement:

[image]

The top display is an actual connected display and the bottom one is a virtual one that the computer thinks is there. It's driving me nuts, because there will always be a side of my screen where my cursor will go out into the void and get lost. Is there any solution to this problem?